# Group by two columns and add column

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have the following table,

```
+-------+----------+-------+-------+
| Date  | Exchange | price |     x | 
+-------+----------+-------+-------+
| 02/12 | LSE      |     1 |  s    |
| 03/12 | LSE      |     2 |  d    |
| 03/12 | LSE      |     2 |  f    |
| 03/12 | CBOE     |     3 |  q    |
| 04/12 | CBOE     |     4 |  w    |
| 04/12 | CBOE     |     5 |  t    |
+-------+----------+-------+-------+
```

I am want to get a table that adds the columns price when the two columns date and exchanges are the same, i.e. the table would look like

```
+-------+----------+-------+
| Date  | Exchange | price |  
+-------+----------+-------+
| 02/12 | LSE      |     1 |  
| 03/12 | LSE      |     4 | 
| 03/12 | CBOE     |     3 |  
| 04/12 | CBOE     |     9 |  
+-------+----------+-------+
```

I tried something but it doesnt work

```
spread_per_isin_size_2500.groupby(['exchange', 'date']).size().groupby(level=1).max()
```

I can i acheive this?

Thanks

Comment: Use `spread_per_isin_size_2500.groupby(['Exchange', 'Date'], as_index=False, sort=False).sum()`

Comment: This seems to sort by the last column on the table. However, the value that needs to be added is not the last column on the table. Can i reference that column?

Comment: If is added `sort=False` it not sorting

Comment: Sorry, meant it ADDS the last column, but the price in my real df is not the last column.

Comment: Not understand, can you create [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Comment: Please look at the edited table. I added a column at the end, so now the sum() will do this on the last column. But i need to sum the price columm. Hope that makes sense?

Comment: Understand, how is changed expected output?

Comment: It is not, same output. The x column should be ignored

Comment: hmmm, so `spread_per_isin_size_2500.groupby(['Exchange', 'Date'], as_index=False, sort=False).sum()` not working? If not, use `spread_per_isin_size_2500.groupby(['Exchange', 'Date'], as_index=False, sort=False)['price'].sum()`

Comment: I have strong feeling it should be duplicate, answered before, so rather not.